# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn' in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I've tried everything, pip to conda, all types of installations possible.
And all the time I got that the required packages are already satisfied/installed.
But when I try to import it in VScode, it doesn't work. There was a similar question, who had the same problem and I did what people suggested there but it didn't help either. Can someone help out here?

I'm using python 3.8.8 version
thanks in advance for the help :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JhVk.png)

Comment: Make sure you installed seaborn in the same environment that you are using in VS code

Comment: @It_is_Chris how do I check and install in the same environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `pip show seaborn` in Jupyter to check if it exists in current environment.

If it does, you should see the following screenshot, `seanborn` stores in `environment\lib\site-packages`:

[image]

If not, please selecting interpreter and opening an integrated Terminal, then install `seaborn` in it. You may also use `pip show seaborn` to check its installation location.

For your reference, view [select and activate environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try changing your Python (3) interpreter, to do this:

- Click the interpreter button in the bottom left (bottom blue ribbon): https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H2AL.png
- Try running with the different Python 3 interpreter paths until you find one which works - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY1Ld.png